# TLP package with Power Mode Settings in Ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: power-management, tlp, 21.04

Should I uninstall the [TLP](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/tlp) package now that Ubuntu 21.04 includes Power Mode settings by default?

In other words, will TLP interfere with the Power Mode settings; are they redundant?

According to the [TLP website](https://linrunner.de/tlp/)...

> TLP is a feature-rich command line utility for Linux, saving laptop battery power without the need to delve deeper into technical details.
>
> TLP’s default settings are already optimized for battery life and implement Powertop’s recommendations out of the box. So you may just install and forget it.

The new Power Mode seems to do the same thing as TLP (except it does need to be selected upon each reboot, but that's how I use TLP anyway with the [TLP Switcher](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1212/tlp-switcher/) extension).

Here's the Power Mode settings in Ubuntu. You can see it has similar options as TLP can be configured with...

[image: Power Mode settings in Ubuntu 21.04]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have two power management tools that might work against each other.
The creator of tlp (linrunner) mentions this on his [FAQ](https://linrunner.de/tlp/faq/powertop.html) concerning powertop. this could be extended to other tools.

I'd switch off TLP with `TLP_ENABLE=0` (without removing it) and test the Ubuntu power management vs TLP (and turn off the Ubuntu part then)

Comment: Your logic makes sense based, backed by the reference you linked to. The default Power Settings included in 21.04 will be good enough for me, so I am just going to uninstall TLP. A side benefit is that I can also uninstall the TLP Switcher extension, since I can easily access the new power settings from the top bar system status drop down menu.

Comment: "... since I can easily access the new power settings from the top bar system status drop down menu."
How is it _easily_ possible? I would like to have an easy to reach switcher. But as far as I know I have to open "Settings", then go to "Power or Energy" before I can switch the Power Mode.
Is there a faster methode to change the Power Mode in 21.04?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, **you should definitely disable (or remove) one of them**. Be aware that the new Power Mode in GNOME's Settings is just an interface to the [power-profiles-daemon project](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/hadess/power-profiles-daemon). The project is not mature enough yet, I guess.

Why it's not mature enough yet?

- Does NOT support a wide range of power management options available in TLP: USB autosuspend, WiFi power saving mode, radio device switching, runtime power management for PCIe devices... etc.
- Does NOT save the currently active profile across system restarts--always starts with the "balanced" profile.

NOTE that **if power-profiles-daemon package is available in your system, it will disable `tlp.service` from running at the system startup** (see [TLP/issues/564](https://github.com/linrunner/TLP/issues/564)). The package is installed by default in Ubuntu 21.04+. You need to remove `power-profiles-daemon` package or disable `power-profiles-daemon.service` systemd unit for TLP to work properly.