# Ubuntu 21.04 - Power mode completely disappeared

Tags: power-management, 21.04, tlp, mode

I have been using Ubuntu 21.04 for a month now and I noticed not too long ago that the Power Mode selection completely disappeared from the Power tab in the settings. I was wondering if it had anything to do with something I previously installed, but I cannot find anything online related to this. I am running Ubuntu on a ThinkPad T14 Gen 2 if that matters.

I also have TLP installed which according to [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1334348/tlp-package-with-power-mode-settings-in-ubuntu-21-04) might interfere with this. Might have to disable one of them once I figure out why the Power Modes are unavailable at the moment.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The TLP 1.4 packages from the PPA disable power-profiles-daemon --> https://linrunner.de/tlp/installation/ubuntu.html

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem

the solution that worked for me by installing the **power-profiles-daemon**

just run in a terminal :

```
sudo apt install power-profiles-daemon
```